# Tooltip for HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

Anyone know a good alternative to the flowplayer tooltip? I need same functionality of HTML content with Tip remaining active when `mouseenter` inside of tooltip as the below demo shows.  Also need tooltip to close `onclick`

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Comment: What's wrong with the flowplayer tooltip? It seems to support the behaviours you require. The documentation states " By default the tooltip stays visible when the mouse is moved over it and it is hidden upon mouseleave. If you don't want to close the tooltip upon mouseleave, you can simply specify: tooltip: "mouseenter". This gives you the possibility of closing the tooltip programmatically. This has been done on the login/signup boxes on the main navigation bar of this website."

Comment: Flowplayer's jQuery Tools is a dead/dying project, IMHO.  The developer had "lost interest" for over a year and it has not been upgraded since jQuery 1.4.2.  This does not mention the unconventional methods, the large amount of HTML/CSS markup or the lack of support in the developer's own forum.  The developer states that the next upgrade will not be backward compatible with your existing markup so the OP might as well move forward with something more up to date and better supported by today's browsers (IE9, IE10, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/demos).  It does everything you'd ever need a Tooltip plugin to do.  It comes preloaded with several CSS themes and the best part is that the developer answers questions in his forum on a daily basis.

http://qtip2.com/demos

http://qtip2.com/guides

---

**EDIT 8/28/13**

Now I prefer a jQuery plugin called **Tooltipster**.  Mainly because it's much easier to configure, and I don't have to do anything to the CSS because I already like how it looks.

http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, links fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I use tooltipsy, this is an EXCELLENT tooltip program. You can set it to do pretty much anything you want. If you want custom CSS, okay, if you want to set your own show and hide events, okay, you can change what the tooltip aligns to, the delay until it shows, you can do whatever you want. Tootipsy is the best one I ever used. (I had to make a little modification to it to get it to use HTML in the tooltips though, but it's a very simple change)

Answer (score 0):

What about [Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/)?

Comment: Prototip requires PrototypeJS, the user tagged jQuery as the framework he's using.