# How to make an Information Box slide out from right of a link onHover?

Tags: javascript, css, html, slide

Basically what I want is some code so when someone hovers over a link (in my #navigation bar), a little box slides out to the right of it explaining what the link is. If possible, I would like it so the box moves the other links to the right with it, but if that's not possible than a box that just goes over it is fine. Hopefully you all understand what I'm asking and are able to guide me. Thanks!

Comment: and what have you tried to achieve this ?

Comment: I've tried playing around with onHover but I fail at JS. I've also tried to look it up, but it's really hard to put it in words over Google.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for  [these so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tooltip+html+)  for implementation help for tooltip using jQuery etc. But you can use the [title property to show tooltip](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_title.asp).
You don't need JavaScript for this at all; just set the title attribute:
'

Name

’

Note that the visual presentation of the tooltip is browser/OS dependent, so it might fade in and it might not. However, this is the semantic way to do tooltips, and it will work correctly with accessibility software like screen readers.

See this [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MpnvA/)

if you need more functionality with tooltip then use jQuery.
Ref- [Tooltip for HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664791/tooltip-for-html-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, perfect from what you mentioned:

look at the blue contact button on the left.

http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

or this:

http://www.craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

cleck demos, then look under the second section under effects title, second link down

hope this helps